# Raspberry Pico W network test fails

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I just put my hands on RP Pico W to try it out but I hit the issue with the very first wifi test.
Tutorials say to do this:

```
import network
import socket
from time import sleep
from picozero import pico_temp_sensor, pico_led
import machine
```

so my pico lib folder looks like this when I imported all required packages:

[image]

However when try to run wifi test like this:

```
def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        sleep(1)
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f'Connected on {ip}')


try:
    connect()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    machine.reset()
```

it fails with following error:

```
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/lib/network.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/lib/socket.py", line 42, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'socket'
>>>
```

This is whole code, I skipped only ssid and password.

I cannot figure out what exactly is wrong here. I do not have any other files named the same as socket or so.

I took the example from RP foundation pages:
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/get-started-pico-w/2

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out the picozero import if you just want to test connecting to wireless.  It worked for me.  Below is the output.

```
//from picozero import pico_temp_sensor, pico_led


MicroPython v1.22.0 on 2023-12-27; Raspberry Pi Pico W with RP2040
Type "help()" for more information.
>>> %Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT
Waiting for connection...
Waiting for connection...
Waiting for connection...
Connected on 192.168.0.219
>>>
```